# How to get the character after an element in Javascript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Let's say I have a block of HTML like this:

```
<div class="text">
    Hello <span class="word">world</span>! This is a test example.
</div>
```

How would I retrieve the character right after the SPAN "word" element, which in this case is the (!) exclamation point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With vanilla JS you can use [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to get the next node and then [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) to get its value:

```js
const word = document.querySelector('.word');

console.log(word.nextSibling.nodeValue);
```

```html
<div class="text">
  Hello <span class="word">world</span>! This is a test example.
</div>
```

You can easily adapt this to work with jQuery:

```js
const $word = $('.word');

// Simply get the native JS object and access `.nextSibling.nodeValue` on that:
console.log($word.get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue);
```

```html
<div class="text">
  Hello <span class="word">world</span>! This is a test example.
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note the difference between [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling), that returns nodes, and [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling), that only returns elements, so it will return `null` if you use it in the examples above.